# Kotlin 0.11.91 Unresolved Reference: inv()

Tags: kotlin

I'm using Kotlin 0.11.91 and getting an unresolved reference on the bitwise inversion function inv(). No other functions are having this problem.

```
var h = hash + inv(hash shl 9)
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite your code in the following ways:

```
var h = hash + (hash shl 9).inv()
```

Comment: This is because `inv()` is an extension function on `Int` and therefore must be called in the form of `someInt.inv()` or in the case of this example called on the results of the expression that produces the `Int` value.  In the API reference are docs for this and other [`Int` Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html)